# SQL Join using Parallel Processing

Tags: sql, oracle, join, parallel-processing

I'm new to the parallel processing concept. I read through [Oracle's white paper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/datawarehouse/twp-parallel-execution-fundamentals-133639.pdf) here to learn the basics but am unsure of how to best construct a SQL join to take advantage of parallel processing. I'm querying my company's database which is massive. The first table is products which is 1 entry per product with product details and the other is sales by week by store by product.

```
Sales:

    Week   Store    Product   OtherColumns
    1      S100      prodA
    2      S100      prodB
    3      S100      prodC
    1      S200      prodA
    2      S200      prodB
    3      S200      prodC
```

I need to join the 2 tables based on a list of product I specify. My query looks like this:

```
select *

from
    (select prod_id, upc
     from prod_tbl
     where upc in (...)) prod_tbl
join
    (select location, prod_id, sum(adj_cost), sum(sales), row_number() over (partition by loc_id order by sum(adj_cost))
     from wk_sales
     group by...
     having sum(adj_cost)< 0) sales_tbl
on prod_tbl.prod_id = sales_tbl.prod_id
```

The left table in the join processes a lot faster because it's just one entry per product. The right table is incredibly slow even without the calculations. So here's my question(s):

1. To parallel process the right table (sales_tbl), do I restructure like so:

   `...
   join
       select location, sum(), ...more
       from (select ...fields... from same_tbl) --no calculations in table subquery
       where
       group by
   on ...`
2. Am I able to change the redistribution method to broadcast since the first return set is drastically smaller?

Comment: Do you want to use parallel execution for your query? If yes then why dud you mentioned about PL/SQL in the subject? That's confusing.

Comment: In your case it does not matter if you use one bug query of nested one into another. I would say it is weird to use aggregation and analytics at the same time. Why do you need row_number?

Comment: What I got from the paper I read was that there should be a PX receive and a PX send. The row_number is actually a filter for the HAVING clause. (select only top x of adj_cost)

Comment: The paper provided a couple examples on how to force parallel execution with hints but pointed out that hints are for testing purposes. I was wondering how I could use parallel execution without using hints.

Comment: Re analytics - it does not make sense to me. I don't see how you use it. Forget for the moment about parallel and just try to write your query. Then just add paralell hint. It is not a fact that it will run faster. Also take into account fetching time - most GUI fetch only first N rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use parallel execution all you need is to add `PARALLEL` hint. Optionally you can also specify degree like:

```
/*+ parallel(4) */
```

In you query you need to make sure that it uses full scan and hash joins. To do that you need check you plan. Parallel is not very efficient for nested loops and merge joins.

Update: small hint regarding parallel - bear in mind that parallel scan bypasses buffer cache. So if you read big table many times in different sessions it might be better to use serial read. Consider parallel only for one off tasks like ETL jobs and data migration.